# How to make IE8 only to work in compatibility mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

IE8 has it's own bugs which are not present in IE6, IE7, IE8 compat. mode and IE9 beta...
i.e.: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hidden-visible-broken-in-ie8

Is there any way to force compatibility mode for IE8 only?

1. When i try to put in the header something like:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE7; IE9" />`

IE8 doc type falls back to IE8 mode

1. When i try:

   ```
   <!--[if IE 8]>
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>
   <![endif]-->
   ```

IE8 renders the meta-tag but completely ignores it

Am i out of options, except for turning IE7 document mode for every IE>7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

This makes IE8 go into IE7 Compatibility mode, but leaves IE9 alone in IE9 mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following without semi-colon

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<![endif]-->
```

This works for me and the test http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hidden-visible-broken-in-ie8 also works

Let me know if this works for you as well

Comment: Still the same - just copied from your message and put into <head> of the masterpage. Doesn't switch IE8 into compat. mode with <!--[if IE 8]> directive. Does switch it without them.
As for the jquery bug - i have same bug as in description but my layout is different

Answer (score 0):

this sets your your old browser i.e IE 6,5 or 8 content compatible automatic,even if you working on latest browser i.e 10 or 11
Eg: this is for IE7.......

...meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">

Comment: But the question is about IE8 only. Not any newer version.